# multiple function in keypress, call the second function until the first function is finished

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, keypress

So I have a input name age, and another input name ageDif, ageDif is readonly and is depend on age, so 50-age = ageDif.

html file

```
<div>
  <label>Age</label>
  <input required name="age" id="age" (keypress)="justnumeric($event); calculateAgeDif()" [(ngModel)]="age"/>
</div>
  <label>Age Difference</label>
  <input name="age difference"  [(ngModel)]="ageDif"/>
</div>
```

ts. file

```
 justnumeric(event): boolean {    
      let pattern = /^([0-9])$/;
      let result = pattern.test(event.key);
      return result;
  }

  calculateAgeDif(){
    this.ageDif = 50- this.age;
  }
```

the problem is that it only take the first digit entered. so if i enter 22 as age, the ageDif is gonna be 48, and 28.

Comment: Firstly, try using this regex instead ```/^([0-9])[2]/```...

Comment: You used keypress event so it is obvious that the age first takes 2 and then 22 giving ageDif 48 and 28

Comment: If you want it to change only once then use change event not keypress

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the `ageDif` to be calculated after your input check from `justnumeric(event)` has been validated then you need to change the event handling to use `(change)` for calculating `ageDif` as below:

```
<input required name="age" id="age" (keypress)="justnumeric($event);" (change)="calculateAgeDif()" [(ngModel)]="age"/>
```

Here `(change)` is not triggered until the input value is not changed and the `(keypress)` event will only allow the numeric values as you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use reactive forms with this kind of functionality to getter to use their observable API on inputs.

age.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-age',
  templateUrl: './age.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./age.component.scss']
})
export class AgeComponent implements OnInit {

  age: FormGroup;

  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
     this.age = builder.group({
       age: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^([0-9])[2]/)]]
     });
  }

  calculateAgeDif(): Observable<number> {
    return this.age.controls['age'].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        map((value) => 50 - value)
      );
      // so you are now watching the form here and calculating the age dif at once
  }
}
```

age.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="age">
  <label>Age</label>
  <input name="age" id="age" formControlName="age"/>
</div>
  <label>Age Difference</label>
  <input name="age difference"  [value]="calculateAgeDif() | async"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Call only justNumeric here and call the ageDiff function in this justNumeric method.
<input required name="age" id="age" (keypress)="justnumeric($event)" [(ngModel)]="age"/>

// In component.ts file, 
 justnumeric(event): boolean {    
      let pattern = /^([0-9])$/;
      let result = pattern.test(event.key);
      this.calculateAgeDif(); // This is the preferred way of angular method calling
      return result;
  }

  calculateAgeDif(){
    this.ageDif = 50- this.age;
  }
```